# Reading C++ generated bin file C++ int/double array, in python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a double or int array into a binary file. Thereafter, open the c++ generated bin file in python. However, I'm just receiving wrong answers.

I can see multiple questions. However, they all seem to induvidually write the int/doubles from the array using a for loop.

However, none of them are reading an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
std::fstream w_s;
std::fstream r_s;
int trial_int[3+1];
int * thpoint;
int trial_2[3+1];
int * thpoint2;
char the_chars;
int i;
int main() {
    
    w_s.open("randombin.dat",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    
    if(w_s.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    trial_int[0] = 0;
    trial_int[1] = 1;
    trial_int[2] = 2;

    thpoint = trial_int;

    int sizeofthearray = sizeof(trial_int)/sizeof(trial_int[0]);

    w_s.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeofthearray), sizeof(int));
    w_s.write((char *) &thpoint, sizeof(&thpoint));
    w_s.close();


    r_s.open("randombin.dat",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if(r_s.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    thpoint2 = trial_2;
    int thesize;

    r_s.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&thesize), sizeof(int));
    r_s.read((char *) &thpoint2, sizeof(&thpoint2));

    r_s.close();

    std::cout << "thesize = " << thesize << std::endl;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << thpoint2[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can easily read this new bin file in c++.
Output:

```
thesize = 4
0
1
2
```

However, how do read this in python?

```
import re
import struct
import numpy as np


with open("randombin.dat", mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
    
print(fileContent)

after0 = struct.unpack("i", fileContent[:4])
after1 = struct.unpack("ii", fileContent[4:12])
after2 = struct.unpack("iii", fileContent)

print(after0)
print(after1)
print(after2)

f = open('randombin.dat', 'rb')
arr1 = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int16)
print(arr1)

f.close()
```

Output:

```
(4,)
(20686464, 1)
(4, 20686464, 1)
[     4      0 -22912    315      1      0]
```

As you can clearly see... I do receive the first integer. However, I'm unsure how to gain the array.

Comment: Before testing your Python code, you should better test your C++ code. It looks like it will fail miserably if your array is larger, say 12 integers instead of 3. (Also, why do you consider `thesize = 4` to be correct when the array has only **3** elements?)

Comment: A good debugging step would be to look at your file with something like a hex viewer. That would let you see what is actually in the file, removing the need to assume that your C++ code for reading the data is bug-free. In addition, you could completely remove the C++ code from your question if you simply had the data file you wish to read. (For a file this short, writing the contents as bytes in hexadecimal notation should not be to cumbersome.) Or, alternatively, remove the Python until the C++ code produces the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. Taking the sizeof(trial_int) gives me 16, that is why I divide by one of the size_of() positions. The array does have 4 positions in the trial_int[3+1]. However, it is correct what you are saying as I have not filled the last position (mistake by me, new to c++). However, trying to use 3 positions only gives me the same type of results regardless. When I do make it 12 integers with 12 positions, my c++ does not fail miserably. I'm unsure what you mean with that. Thanks!

Comment: By "fail miserably" I  mean that the less than the entire array will be written to the file (because `sizeof(&thpoint)` is the size of a pointer, independent of the size of your array).